# Capture Visible Webpage Content (or text) as if Copying from Browser

Tags: python, selenium, screen-scraping, web-scraping, screenshot

Is there a way to capture visible webpage content or text as if copying from a browser display to parse later (maybe using regular expression etc)? I don't mean to clean the html tags, javascript, etc and only show leftover text.  I would like to copy all visible text, since some style elements may hide some of the html text while showing others when displayed in the browser.  So far I have looked into nltk, lxml Cleaner, and selenium without luck.  Maybe I can capture a screenshot in selenium and then extract text using ocr, but that seems computer intensive?  Thanks for any help!

Comment: Look [here](http://www.sagehill.net/docbookxsl/FormattedText.html)

Comment: Short answer: No. I have the distinct feeling you are barking up the wrong tree, What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: @inspectorG4dget: i tried all three progs mentioned without luck.  They example I am working with is "http://www.hidemyass.com/proxy-list/".  The correct IPs show up when displayed, but if you look at the html, or html to text, the real IPs are obfuscated.  Eek

Comment: @LennartRegebro: But those damn cats!!!  I'm trying to achieve a simpler way to scrap from convoluted html, but the issue was sparked by trying to scrape IPs from "hidemyass.com/proxy-list/".

Comment: @WacKaDoodle: that's tough, because HMA uses some sort of proxying and what-not. This is beyond my expertise

Answer (score 2):

Sure. Use Selenium and just loop through all visible, displayable elements.

Comment: Sweet!  Didn't realize it had that method.